# Differential of vector field

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curves, vector-fields

Given smooth manifolds $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ and a smooth map $f : \mathcal M \to \mathcal N$, we define the differential of $f$ at $p \in \mathcal M$ as the linear map
\begin{align}
\text{d}f_{p} : \mathcal T_{p}\mathcal M &\to \mathcal T_{f(p)}\mathcal N \\
\gamma'(0) &\mapsto (f \circ \gamma)'(0),
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ is a smooth curve on $\mathcal M$ satisfying $\gamma(0) = p$. Since a vector field is a smooth map $X : \mathcal M \to \mathcal T \mathcal M$ and $\mathcal T \mathcal M$ is itself a smooth manifold, why can't we just apply the above definition to $X$? Why do we instead need the notions of connections and covariant derivatives? Isn't $(X \circ \gamma)'(0)$ a perfectly sensible tangent vector in the tangent space of $\mathcal T \mathcal M$ at $X(p)$?

Comment: Well, the issue is that when you differentiate vector fields normally the difference quotient is not properly defined since its different components live in different tangent spaces. Connections and Lie derivatives fix this issue by using parallel transport and flows respectively.

Comment: You can define this, but then, $dX_p$ would be a map from $T_pM$ to $T_{X_p}(TM)\subset T(TM)$, the latter being not canonically related to $T_pM$

Comment: @NicholasJames It's weird, because as far as I can tell, we have $(f \circ \gamma)'(0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(\gamma(t)) - f(p)}{t}$. Wouldn't this require some notion of addition/subtraction on $\mathcal N$? It doesn't seem well defined.

Comment: @NicholasJames In the embedded case given that we have a Riemannian metric on $\mathcal M$, would it then be reasonable to define the differential of a vector field simply by projecting $\gamma''(0)$ onto the tangent space of $\mathcal M$ at $\gamma(0)$?

Comment: @markusas  In regards to your most recent comment, the Levi-Civita connection does the job. It's just much more general and doesn't require the choice of $\gamma$. As for your previous comment, that's perfectly fine to say. What you wrote is just another way of saying
$$(f\circ \gamma)'(0)=d\gamma\left(\frac{d}{dt}\biggr|_{t_0=0}\right)f=\gamma'(0)(f)$$
where you're treating $\gamma'$ as a map from $C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The issue isn't evaluating the derivative of $\gamma$, but finding the acceleration of a smooth curve. When you do *that*, this is where problems occur.